# Strange behavior in IIS bindings

Tags: iis, sharepoint, binding, sharepoint-2010, iis-6

My company's Sharepoint 2010 site currently has two different bindings: [A] for use inside my company's local network and [B] for external use.

One of our sub-sites created in ASP.NET is located on Port 8001 which we will call [C].

Whenever a user tries to access [C], there is success when the user tries accessing http://[A]:8001/[C] but the page cannot be displayed if the user tries to access http://[B]:8001/[C].

I'm looking for solutions in IIS 6.1 but I have found nothing. If anyone has any experience with IIS binding issues, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it could be a few things The most common are probably:

1) one is that C may not be bound to both internal and external IPs/interfaces. But rather is bound only to A

2) Port 8001 on your external facing IP is being blocked by your firewall/intrusion devices. For that matter it could be being blocked by windows firewall too.